# How can i turn Stringbuilder variable to a long?

Tags: android, number-formatting

```
// Get the text file
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Config/GPSListenerminTime.cfg");

        // Read text from file
        StringBuilder GPSListenerminTime = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                GPSListenerminTime.append(line);
                GPSListenerminTime.append('\n');

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO You'll need to add proper error handling here
        }
```

I want to read a number from a file with this code and it works well, but how can i use that number as a long value in the requestLocationUpdates?
I tried to use it this way but it is not working:

```
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(GPSListenerminTime)), 0, this);
```

My file only contains this number: 10000
I get this error when i staring the service:

```
  08-07 15:32:45.599: E/AndroidRuntime(19878): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to create service com.example.gpslog.DataLogService: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumberFormatException is a result of parsing "1000/n" string. Just remove all empty characters with trim() method :

```
Long.valueOf(yourStringBuilder.toString().trim());
```

Comment: no, he had edited his answer after mine;) Anyway I'm giving my +1 to him

Answer (score 1):

Your currently using `Long.valueOf` this encapsulates `Long.parseLong` so you can ignore the answers suggesting using that.

As you are receiving a number format exception it's likely your string contains leading or trailing whitespace try using;

```
Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(GPSListenerminTime).trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet that should work:

```
long requestLong = Long.parseLong(GPSListenerminTime.toString());
```

Basically, you're converting your `StringBuilder` to a regular `String`, and then letting the `Long` class parse it.

Comment: If you read their code they are using Long.valueOf, this already encapsulates Long.parseLong.

Comment: I tried it and the String.valueOf but i get the same numberformatexception.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
StringBuilder oBuilder = your_string_builder;
long myLong = Long.parseLong(oBuilder.toString());
```